# Why does my Angular application give an error when run on StackBlitz?

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I have an Angular application that runs fine on my machine using `ng serve`, but when I run it on StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/github/nickhodges/primedirective

I get the following error:

```
Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@7.0.4/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2617:21)
Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
```

I have updated the dependencies on the StackBlitz editor, and it still doesn't work, giving a slightly different error.

```
Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@7.1.0/bundles/compiler.umd.js (2497:21)
Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
```

Anyone have any idea why this error occurs on StackBlitz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` include this line in your `polyfills.ts`

visit the link its working now https://github-pigpd9.stackblitz.io 
and  https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pigpd9 (editorial url)

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  You were first, and in five minutes, I will accept your answer.

Comment: This solution no longer works with Angular 8.1.3. Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

yes this is because we have to import

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

in our polyfils.ts file. 
after including this it will work.

there is only one reason why it's happing and you can read that reason in the introduction to [angular 7](https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c)

this is happening when we upgrade Angular 5 to Angular 7

Comment: there is only one reason why it's happing and you can read that reason in introduction to angular 7 https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c

Comment: Thank you -- you were correct, but Vaibhav Kumar Goyal was first.  ;-)

Comment: haha not an issue, we all are here to help each other. that doesn't matter. happy coding brother.